# How To Return Elapsed Time From steady_clock as a Primitive Data Type (double)

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

First and foremost, let me say that I just starting using this library yesterday, so my understanding of it is still fairly basic. I'm trying to capture the FPS of a vision processing program I'm creating and output it to a screen using the *chrono* library. In my case, I need to cast the elapsed time taken after I start a *steady_clock* to a **double** (or some other numerical typedef I could treat like a double). I looked through reference documentation and tried working with the *duration_cast* and *time_point_cast* functions, but neither of those seem to be what I'm looking for.

My question is; is there any way to simply cast the numerical value of a clock's current state in seconds to a primitive data type?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;

  // measure time now
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  // wait some time
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

  // measure time again
  auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  // define a double-precision representation of seconds
  using fsecs = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds::period>;

  // convert from clock's duration type
  auto as_fseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<fsecs>(end - start);

  // display as decimal seconds
  std::cout << "duration was " << as_fseconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

example output:

```
duration was 1.00006s
```

Comment: You can also default the second parameter on `duration` here if you like:  `using secs = std::chrono::duration<double>;`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the [`duration::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) function.

For example you could get the duration in the number of milliseconds, and then divide [the count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) by `1000.0` to get the number of seconds as a `double`.